# how to load user_email from database and post it in $to of Php wp_mail() function

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer

I am trying to send birthday mail to the registered user using the PHP wp_mail() function of wordpress. However, I am not able to send the email. Please into the code below:

```
# Get user ID
$id = get_current_user_id();

global $wpdb;

//query to extract  birthdate from database 
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT um.meta_value FROM `wp_usermeta` AS um WHERE um.user_id = $id AND um.meta_key = 'birth_date'");

//query to extract email from database
$query= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT u.user_email FROM `wp_users` AS u WHERE u.ID = $id");


//load data from database and store it in user_name variable

foreach ($query as $row1) {
    $user_name =  $row1->user_email;
       
        
}
//birth_date 
$newDate = date("d-m", strtotime($birth_date ));  
//echo "birth date format is: ".$newDate;  

//present date
//$now = time();
//$newNow= date("d-m", strtotime($now));  
$newNow = date("d-m");
//echo "Today date format is: ".$newNow; 


if ($newDate == $newNow) { 
    
    $to = $user_name;
    $subject = 'Happy Birthday';
       

    $body = 'Hello Gaurav';
    wp_mail( $to, $subject,$body );

 
}

?>
```

In the code above I tried putting `$to=$user_name` in the $to section, it does not send emails to the registered user. However, If I put an entire email address manually i.e.  `$to= "xyz@gmail.com"` the xyz user receives emails successfully.

Comment: If you re-read your last part of the question, you'll see "if I use X, it does not work, but when I manually do it, it works" -- This indicates that X (or $user_name) is your problem, print it out and see if it even has anything.

Comment: Look at get_userdata() it's a better way to get the email of a user by ID: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_userdata/

Comment: Hey @Jesse I checked and it does have email address which I extracted from the database

Comment: Hey, @Hillel I will look into that.Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I revised your code. you should check `email` is empty or not. try the below code.

For email you can get user using `get_user_by()`

```
$user = get_user_by( 'id', get_current_user_id() );
```

To retrieve user meta you can use `get_user_meta()` function.

```
$birth_date = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'birth_date', true );

function sent_birthday_mail(){

    $user = get_user_by( 'id', get_current_user_id() );

    if ( $user ) {
        $email      = $user->user_email;
        $birth_date = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'birth_date', true );
        $birth_date = date("d-m", strtotime( $birth_date ) );
        $today_date = date("d-m");

        if ( $email != '' && $today_date == $birth_date) { 
            $to      = $email;
            $subject = 'Happy Birthday';
            $body    = 'Hello '.$user->first_name;
            if( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body ) ){
                echo "sent";
            }
        }
    }

}
add_action( 'init', 'sent_birthday_mail', 10, 1 );
```

Also, you can check wp_mail error using WP `wp_mail_failed` action hook.

```
// show wp_mail() errors
add_action( 'wp_mail_failed', 'onWPMailError', 10, 1 );
function onWPMailError( $wp_error ) {
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($wp_error); echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: Hey @Bhautik. Thanks for the detailed explanation.However, I tried copy-pasting the entire code still I am not able to receive email. Being a novice when it comes to PHP i feel I am doing something wrong. Can you please help?

Comment: I am usually write PHP code in XYZ PHP snippet plugin and then insert that on the webpage using shortcode.. For the code above should I add this in ThemeEditor or  should I create a new snippet and add ShortCode to webpage?

Comment: I usually write*

Comment: did you check this action `add_action( 'wp_mail_failed', 'onWPMailError', 10, 1 );`?

Comment: Welcome... glad to be of help.